# Recursive XSL template call with param

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, recursion, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to accomplish a page navigation with the following code.
Although this code is dumbed down to the important parts, it should be clear what my idea is.
The IDs can be any given name and can appear in any given number in any given order.

Input: Pages that define their previous and next pages in a sorted collection:

```
<pages>
  <page id="page1" next="page2" />
  <page id="page2" prev="page1" next="page3" />
  <page id="page3" prev="page2" />
  <page id="test2" prev="test1" />
  <page id="test1" next="test2" />
  <page id="alone" />
</pages>
```

Desired output (which I'm NOT able to generate):

```
<page id="page1">
  <link href="page1" class="active" />
  <link href="page2" />
  <link href="page3" />
</page>
<page id="page2">
  <link href="page1" />
  <link href="page2" class="active" />
  <link href="page3" />
</page>
<page id="page3">
  <link href="page1" />
  <link href="page2" />
  <link href="page3" class="active" />
</page>
<page id="test1">
  <link href="test1" class="active" />
  <link href="test2 />
</page>
<page id="test2">
  <link href="test1" />
  <link href="test2" class="active" />
</page>
<page id="alone">
</page>
```

What I've tried so far with XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:for-each select="pages/page">
  <page id="{@id}">

    <xsl:call-template name="prev-page">
      <xsl:with-param name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@prev" />
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <link href="{@id}" class="active" />

    <xsl:call-template name="next-page">
      <xsl:with-param name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@next" />
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>

  </page>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="prev-page">
  <xsl:param name="id" />

  <xsl:if test="string-length($id) > 0">
    <link href="{$id}" />
    <xsl:call-template name="prev-page">
      <xsl:with-param name="id">
        <!-- I believe in here lies the problem -->
        <xsl:value-of select="(/pages/page[@id = $id])[0]/@prev" />
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
... (same for page-next)
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the prev/next attributes play no role in the output? Or do you need them to establish the order?

Comment: They establish the order. The order of the pages in input is random. I basically want to sort them with the prev and next attributes.

Comment: OMG. Which version of XSLT?

Comment: 1.0, I updated the code with version as well

Comment: OK but you can not insert a `<xsl:for-each>` under an `<xsl:stylesheet>` -- it needs to be nested in an `<xsl:template>` of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inspiration from michael.hor257k I came up with my own solution. I traverse the linked list back until I reach the page where the @prev attribute points to a non existing page. Then I traverse the list forward and print out the  element until the @next attribute points to a non existing page.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="page">
    <page id="{@id}">
      <xsl:if test="string-length(@next) > 0 or string-length(@prev) > 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="page-navigation-reverse">
          <xsl:with-param name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@prev" />
          </xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="current-id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
          </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </page>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="page-navigation-reverse">
  <xsl:param name="id" />
  <xsl:param name="current-id" />

  <xsl:variable name="item-id">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($id) &lt;= 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="$current-id" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$id" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="//page[@id = $item-id]/@prev">

      <xsl:call-template name="page-navigation-reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="//page[@id = $item-id]/@prev" />
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="current-id">
          <xsl:value-of select="$current-id" />
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="page-navigation-forward">
        <xsl:with-param name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="$item-id" />
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="current-id">
          <xsl:value-of select="$current-id" />
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>

  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="page-navigation-forward">
  <xsl:param name="id" />
  <xsl:param name="current-id" />

  <link href="{$id}">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:if test="$id = $current-id">
        <xsl:text> active</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </link>

  <xsl:if test="//page[@id = $id]/@next">
    <xsl:call-template name="page-navigation-forward">
      <xsl:with-param name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="//page[@id = $id]/@next" />
      </xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="current-id">
        <xsl:value-of select="$current-id" />
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to arrange the pages themselves, not just the links, in the "correct" order. Your solution does not do that - <page id="test2"> comes before <page id="test1">. --- The other thing is that you are repeatedly rearranging each "chain" as many times as there are links in the chain. That's very inefficient.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. Yes, I just wanted to sort the links. Performance doesn't really matter in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Let me suggest a radically different approach. First, let's get the pages sorted in the required order. Once that is done, output each page in turn, along with the links to (all) other pages:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- first-pass -->
<xsl:key name="page" match="page" use="@id" />

<xsl:variable name="sorted-pages">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pages/page[not(@prev)]" mode="first-pass"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="page" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('page', @next)" mode="first-pass"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="sorted-pages-set" select="exsl:node-set($sorted-pages)/page" />

<!-- final-output -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <pages>
        <xsl:for-each select="$sorted-pages-set">
        <xsl:variable name="current-id" select="@id" />
            <page id="{$current-id}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$sorted-pages-set">
                    <xsl:with-param name="current-id" select="$current-id"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </page>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </pages>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:param name="current-id" />
    <link href="{@id}">
        <xsl:if test="@id=$current-id">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </link>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **test input**:

```
<pages>
    <page id="alone" />
    <page id="fourth" prev="third" next="MISSING" />
    <page id="second" prev="first" next="third" />
    <page id="ii" prev="i" next="iii" />/>  
    <page id="first" next="second" />
    <page id="third" prev="second" next="fourth" />
    <page id="solo" />
    <page id="i" next="ii" />
    <page id="b" prev="a" /> 
    <page id="iii" prev="ii" />
    <page id="PROBLEM" prev="MISSING"/>
    <page id="a" next="b" />
</pages>
```

produces the following **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages>
   <page id="alone">
      <link href="alone" class="active"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="first">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first" class="active"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="second">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second" class="active"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="third">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third" class="active"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="fourth">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth" class="active"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="solo">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo" class="active"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="i">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i" class="active"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="ii">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii" class="active"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="iii">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii" class="active"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="a">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a" class="active"/>
      <link href="b"/>
   </page>
   <page id="b">
      <link href="alone"/>
      <link href="first"/>
      <link href="second"/>
      <link href="third"/>
      <link href="fourth"/>
      <link href="solo"/>
      <link href="i"/>
      <link href="ii"/>
      <link href="iii"/>
      <link href="a"/>
      <link href="b" class="active"/>
   </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Nice but I hope there won't be too many pages because I think after sorting (alphabetically) you will have page1, page10, page11, page2, page3, page4, ... See what I mean :)

Comment: @potame What makes you think so? I don't have **any** sorting applied, neither alphabetical nor numeric.

Comment: Nice XSLT 1.0 code, even it is working perfectly for more than double didgit numbers also, +1.

Comment: Yep, nice put. But I'm always shy with the use of XSL extensions such as exslt.

Comment: Nice approach. Haven't had time to test this, but there may be a problem with this. Because I forgot to mention, that inside the input element <pages/> can be any amount of disjoint lists of pages. Even pages with no next and prev attribute are possible. Will try the code and maybe extend it and will report back in a day.

Comment: @SebastianHäni If you have pages with no next and prev attribute, then you have no way to establish a predetermined order. The above stylesheet will create a "chain" for any page that does not have a prev attribute, and do so in document order. But if you have a page that points a non-existing prev page, that page will be left out.

Comment: @potame There's really no reason to shy away from EXSLT - it's a well-established (and desperately needed, especially the `node-set()` function) extension for XSLT 1.0. Are you trying to criticize at any rate?

Comment: @SebastianHäni I have updated my input example to better illustrate how this works; please note the two pages with MISSING links.